Recursion depth ( or maybe call stack size ) of quick sort algorithm
I am finding the recursion depth or the level of the best case for the quick sort algorithm.
Reference book, Google and all other resources all giving me the answer that recursion depth of the best case for quick sort algorithm is log n. However ,drawing the recursion tree out, the recursion depth supposed to be log n + 1 from the top to the base case. So, why is log n.

Stack space can be limited to ⌈log2(n)⌉ by using recursion for the smaller partition and iterating for the larger partition. Worst cast time complexity remains O(n^2).
void QuickSort(int a[], int lo, int hi)
{
    while(lo < hi){
        int p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
        int i = lo-1;
        int j = hi+1;
        while (1){
            while(a[++i] < p);
            while(a[--j] > p);
            if(i >= j)
                break;
            std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
        if(j - lo < hi - j){
            QuickSort(a, lo, j);
            lo = j+1;
        } else {
            QuickSort(a, j+1, hi);
            hi = j;
        }
    }
}

Note that Lomuto doesn't include the pivot element when recursing, so it's best case may be slightly less than ⌈log2(n)⌉.

Let's see with Hoare's partition scheme, which in the best case partitions an even-sized array into equal sized partitions.
When you have an array with 1 element, no partitioning occurs. The recursion tree exists of just a root node. The height of that tree is 0, which is log21.
When you have an array with 2 elements, it is partitioned into two arrays of 1, this is a recursion tree with a root and two leaves. It's height is 1, which is log22.
By induction we can see that when the array has a size  that is a power of 2, the height of the recursion tree is log2.
Maybe you used an alternative definition of depth, but Wikipedia defines it as:

The depth of a node is the length of the path to its root (i.e., its root path). Thus the root node has depth zero...

Also, be aware that the number of levels in a tree is one more than its height, or the depth of its deepest leaf node.
To generalize when the array size  is not necessarily a power of 2: the best case will have a maximum recursion depth of ⌈log2⌉, which in case  is not a power 2, is the same as 1 + ⌊log2⌋.
But more importantly, the 1 more or less is not significant for large . So the recursion tree height, and the number of levels and the call stack size are all O(log).

The height of a recursion tree and the depth a recursion tree is always the same?

Usually depth is given for a node, not for a tree. But yes, if we define the depth of a tree as the greatest depth a node has in that tree, then it is equal to the tree's height. A matter of terminology (see Wikipedia link).
